# How to display Ext.List data in TabPanel?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am very new in Sencha Touch 2. I am trying to develop a simple screen with Tab Panel. In the panel, there will be three tabs- artist, albums and playlist. So when i will click the artist, it should show me the list of artist names. This artist name i am keeping in one store file. I wrote the code for view, store and model. But is it require to write the code code for container also? Because i am getting a empty list with 3 rows.
Here is senchafiddle link for my app: [Sencha fiddle link](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#AOZGY)

Please help me. As i am pretty new in Sencha Touch 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Javascript is case-sensitive.

It seems that you want to name your field **firstName**. So take a look at your model definition and simply change it to:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.modelname', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'firstName' //it's 'firstname' before
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Yah..it is working. Thanks a lot. I am newbie in Javascript also. :)

Comment: How can i make this list rounded??